# Increasing understanding map function() and syntax

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var watchList = [
   {
      "Metascore": "70",
      "imdbRating": "8.3",
      "imdbVotes": "972,584",
      "imdbID": "tt0372784",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Response": "True"
   },
   {

      "Metascore": "83",
      "imdbRating": "7.9",
      "imdbVotes": "876,575",
      "imdbID": "tt0499549",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Response": "True"
   }
  ];

console.log(watchList.length);

const rating = watchList.map((function test (item) { 
  console.log(item);
  return {
    title: item["Title"],
    rating: item["imdbRating"]
  };
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(rating));
```

**MDN link**

Just have a few questions in relation to `map()` syntax in my specific code block.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

**Use of map:**

```
`const rating = watchList.map((function test (item) {}`
```

Referencing against the MDN JavaScript docs am I correct in saying that in this case:

1) That `test` is the argument supplied to the *callback* parameter of the `map()` method? It does not state *callback* is an optional parameter, so I'm confused going against the MDN syntax above that there are no errors in the console when an anonymous function is passed that has no name.

2) That `item` is the argument supplied to the `currentValue` parameter of the `map()` method which is each element in the watchList array?

Comment: 1) yes; 2) yes. Though it doesn't make much sense to use a *named* function for the callback - it would more likely be an anonymous one.

Comment: @Utkanos — It's useful for debugging (it shows up in stacktraces).

Comment: If I name the function as i have done can I see it in the console anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDN docs specify what type of function that should be passed like the signature. For description, they have used a name function called the callback.
any function named or anonymous will do the work.

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

here the index and the array are optional

[image]

so for the first question it's a yes

And for the second point you mentioned, the item maps to the current value so it is a yes too. For further learn about passing functions to methods or functional programming concepts with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in MDN:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

it's as write

```
var new_array = arr.map(function(item){.....})
```

the value in[] are optional and the last is to bindig the "this"

especially if you will use arrow function

```
var new_array = arr.map(item=>{})
```

you can also create a function

```
function test(item){.....}
```

and use in callback

```
var new_array = arr.map(test(item))
```